# p4 command line submit files without using changelist number or default

Tags: perforce

How do I submit changed files in a folder without using a changelist number or the default option in p4 command line.

I wanna do this to avoid other files in different folder to be submitted due to they were in the same changelist. And I want to submit it by folders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have description in `p4 help submit` which suggests among others this option:

```
p4 submit [-Af -r -f option] -d description file
```

for instance:

```
p4 submit -d "changes to the folder" ./path/myFolder/...
```

It will submit all opened files on default changelist that are in myFolder and in subfolders.